# How to make an atomic transaction if my transaction is based on multiple response with same time

Tags: python, django, transactions, atomic

I am requesting  json response from new Zealand api for a django webproject  but they are passing 5 response of same request with no difference in time and my transaction is commited but frontend user is send 5 mails at the same time

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
  with transaction.atomic():
    thing_that_might_fail()
except SomeError:
  handle_exception()
```